# How to read Go source code in the Goland?

Tags: go, goland

So I get the Go language source code from the github, and then I open it in the Goland.
But you know, when a file imports "runtime", the ide find it in the $GOROOT firstly but not in the project I open, which lead to some errors.
the handsome stack overflow netizens, give me some solutions.

Comment: Do not set `GOROOT`. It has long been obsolete. (The `go` binary finds standard library based from its location in the file system) Instead, set `GOPATH` and put project sources in `$GOPATH/src/host/group/project`. Then add `$GOPATH/bin` to `PATH`. Then in your project run `go mod init`.

Comment: good. thanks for your advanced method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to golang.
If you've cloned a repo from github, and the repo's code is fine.
If your repo containes a file named go.mod, you should try this.

```sh
go mod download
go build .
```

If there is no error. Then you are free to run the program.

Find your `main` function by double clicking `shilft`
You will see a run button on the left of your main function in code area.

try run it !